# Can I save a picture to drawable file in android?

Tags: android, file, bitmap, save, image

My app takes a photo from camera and after some image processing operations I want to save it drawable file in android. It is possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by Drawable file? Drawable is an Object type that holds an image, I don't believe that is a file format. Do you want to save it as .jpg, .png, .bmp ?

Comment: @tim in android project drawable-hdpi file under res. We paste an image under this. Can I save a jpg that taken from camera to that drawable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

You can store it into the internal memory. See the link for the details:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: where is this file created? Can I see them or do it created virtually?

Comment: @barzos it will use your app data folder. You can save it as png or any format you want. You'll have read/write access to that folder within your app. Alternatively, you can save the image to the sdcard (read the same link, external storage)

Comment: but I want to see a new saved image in my windows to look changes between new and old picture. possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need it to be a resource of your app? You could save it to SD card or internal storage using Bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileoutputStream);

Where fileoutputstream is obtained from something like:

```
String pathString = String.format("%s/%s/%s", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),yourDirOnSD, yourFilename);
        File path = new File(pathString);
        path.mkdirs();
```

And then read it back in when you want using BitmapFactory.decodeFromFile();

Note that if the directory you use on SD starts with a period, it will be exempt from being scanned by the Android media scanner so items in it wont show up in the users photo gallery app, etc. If you want the photo to be visible to other apps, you should probably look into use MediaScanner to have it index your pic once save, otherwise it wont show up until the SD card id remounted.